# Hadoop - Classic MapReduce Wordcount

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my Reducer code, I am using this code snippet to sum the values:

```
for(IntWritable val : values) {
    sum += val.get();           
}
```

As the above mentioned gives me expected output, I tried changing the code to:

```
for(IntWritable val : values) {
    sum += 1;
}
```

Can anyone please explain what is the difference it makes when I use `sum += 1` in the reducer rather than `sum += val.get()`? Why does it give me the same output? Does it have anything to do with Combiner, because when I used this same reducer code as Combiner, class the output was incorrect with all words showing a count of 1.

Mapper Code :

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line);

        while(token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(token.nextToken());
            context.write(word, new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
```

Reducer Code :

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;

        for(IntWritable val : values) {
            //sum += val.get();
            sum += 1;
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
```

Driver Code:

```
job.setJarByClass(WordCountWithCombiner.class);
        //job.setJobName("WordCount");

        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

Input - "to be or not to be"

Expected Output - (be,2) , (to,2) , (or,1) , (not,1)

But Output i am getting is - (be,1) , (to,1) , (or,1) , (not,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain what is the difference it makes when I use `sum += 1` in the reducer rather than `sum += val.get()`?

Both the statements are performing addition operation. In the first you are counting how many times the `for-loop` has run. In the later, you are are actually doing a sum operation, on the `int` value returned by the each `val` object for a given `key`.

> Why does it give me the same output? Does it have anything to do with Combiner

The answer is **Yes**. It is because of the `Combiner`.

Now lets look at the input you are passing, this will instantiate only one `Mapper`. The output of the `Mapper` is:

```
(to,1), (be,1), (or,1), (not,1), (to,1), (be,1)
```

When this goes to the `Combiner`, which is essentially same logic as `Reducer`. The output will be:

```
(be,2) , (to,2) , (or,1) , (not,1)
```

Now the above output of `Combiner` goes to the `Reducer` and it will perform the sum operation however you define it. So if your logic is `sum += 1` then output will be:

```
(be,1) , (to,1) , (or,1) , (not,1)
```

But if your logic is `sum += val.get()` then your output will be:

```
(be,2) , (to,2) , (or,1) , (not,1)
```

I hope you understand it now. The logic of the `Combiner` and `Reducer` is same, But the input which is coming to them for processing is **different**.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on the value of `sum += val.get();`

If always `val.get()` return **1**, then `sum += val.get();` is the same than `sum += 1;` as it is happening in your reducer.

BUT

The **combainer** is used to do a pre-aggregation (similar than the reducer aggregation) in the mapper side, previous to send the key-values pairs to the recuder(s).

Hadoop framework doesn't warranty the times that the combiner is executed by Mapper, it will depend on the number of Mapper's outputs. Then, if only one time the combiner is executed, the aggregation in the mapper side will be ok but in the reducer instead to only receive **1's** you could receive other number (`val.get() >= 1`). And if you use `sum += 1;` in your reducer, you will be dropping the aggregated numbers in the mapper, generating a wrong output.

If the combiner is executed more than one time in the Mapper side, then you could imagine that the problem could be even worst.

In summary, `sum += 1;` only works **if and only if** that statement is executed only **one time** for each key-value. Using the combiner, that is not warranted.

Answer (score 0):

`val.get();` return an `int` so basically both the codes are same. The reason we are using val.get() depends on the problem we are trying to solve. In your case we are sure that in the mapper each word is emitted as the key and the value as 1, so in the reducer you can be sure that val.get() will always return 1. Hence the hard coded integer value 1 gives the same result.

Also using the same reducer as the combiner function should not cause any problem. One of the scenario where the output would be with all words giving count as '1' would be when the number of reducers is set as 0 and the mapper output is written to the output path.

Comment: Thanks Prabhu but i am still confused with the Combiner part

Comment: I have now added my most of the code. As u can see in the Reducer Part i have commented the actual code "sum += val.get()" and tried with "sum+=1".
When i execute code with -- sum += val.get() -- along with the Combiner and Reducer i get the proper Expected output.
But when i run the code with ::: sum+=1  :::  along with Combiner & Reducer i am getting the count as '1' for all words(which is incorrect)

Comment: I tried the MR program and you are right, when we set a combiner and in the reduce function we use 'sum += 1;' I am getting count as '1' for all words. This is totally weird and confusing me as well. So as of now even I am looking out for a solution to this problem same as you are.

Comment: I just added an answer to explain it.